# Removal of voice from single track in audacity

Tags: audio, editing

Recently I've been recording some game commentary with a friend. We both have our own computers and headsets. Our plans were to swap our voice tracks and edit them in to each others videos, so we'd each have a clear version of each other.

Unfortunately in my friends video you can hear my voice. Mine is very quiet compared to his. I haven't used a tool like Audacity in years and even then I was no expert!

Could anyone point me in the direction (using Audacity or not is fine!) of how to do this? I've had a play around with the "High Pass Filter", however either I'm not setting it right or it's not effective in this case.

I've uploaded a sample of the audio to soundcloud.

http://soundcloud.com/andrew-white-51/test-for-stackexchange/s-CoPBl

My voice is the background one and his is the foreground one.

Thanks all!

Comment: If you need to include audio in your question/answer, you can use [soundcloud](http://soundcloud.com/).  Take a look at [this meta post](http://meta.avp.stackexchange.com/questions/190/youtube-and-soundcloud-embedding-is-now-enabled) for details.

Comment: Link goes to an "Oops" page

Comment: Sorry @Abdias, looks like I missed off a part of the URL! Fixed now

Comment: If you set the sample to public, it will show up with the embedded player here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a few other questions on removing a particular piece of audio - the problem is that it isn't possible without damaging the rest of the sound.

If the audio you are trying to remove is very quiet, so you only hear it during quiet parts of the audio, a noise gate will help you, as @Abdias says. If you can hear it even in the loud sections you will not get rid of it with a noise gate.

Using a filter, you can get rid of all speech by chopping all frequencies in the vocal range - but this also gets rid of any other parts of the audio that lie within that range, so in your example you will lose game sound effects such as the mid range of gunshots, engine noises etc. It works, but you will notice the missing frequencies.

Rather than use a high pass filter, what you want is a paramtric equaliser, which will let you cut a specific frequency range, and then play with it until the frequencies you want removed are no longer audible.

Comment: Thanks for your response! After a ton of trial and error, I did the best I can .I'll record in better circumstances next time!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, high-pass filter will only work on frequencies, not so much volume.

Try to run your sample through a noise-gate. Adjust threshold level till the low-volume stop coming through. Then adjust attack/release to make it sound more natural.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you could take your original recording of your voice and invert the waveform, tweak it (attenuate and EQ) to match the other recording and then merge to two, cancelling out your voice in your friend's recording.

It is worth a try, but I doubt it will work in practice.